# jquery attribute selector variable that contains a quote?

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors, special-characters, quotes

I want to select an input box which has the following ID:

`id="Peoples' Choice"`

If I manually type in the selector with escape characters, it works:

`$("[id='Peoples\\' Choice']")`

But if I use a variable, it doesn't seem to work:

```
var theID = "Peoples' Choice";
var sel = "[id='" + theID + "']"
chk = $(sel);
```

This spews out a syntax error saying unrecognized expression.
I even tried replacing the quote in `theID` with double-backslash+quote.

Help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can escape the special characters in your variable prior to using it in your attribute selector.

You can use the following regex:

```
var sel = "[id='" + theID.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1') + "']"
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/NTPYw/)

Comment: This works for your example, but it fails when there's a space in the ID :( It might be wrong HTML, but is there a way to handle that with this snippet?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle, it works as well with spaces... Although spaces are not allowed in IDs so you should not have them.

Answer (score 4):

`id`s can't have spaces in it. Just use `peoples-choice`.
From w3, http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Well, apparently the existing system where I work can have it :/ Maybe jquery doesn't give a damn about it?

Comment: I am new to web stuff and don't have much experience, but at work, that's how it is and it's working for ids with spaces but no special characters in them.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I doubt folks here are gonna consider rewriting a whole lot of code :(

Comment: @ForeverLearnNeverMaster: At least suggest it. It ain't right.

Answer (score 0):

we cannot put (') in
 id but still you can try this

try this

```
var theID = "Peoples\' Choice";
var sel = "[id='" + theID + "']"
chk = $(sel);
```

instead of

```
var theID = "Peoples' Choice";
var sel = "[id='" + theID + "']"
chk = $(sel);
```